# Can't install Windows 10 ARM64 on Surface Pro X 1876 128GB from USB

Tags: windows-10, installation, usb-flash-drive, microsoft-surface, arm

I can't install *Windows 10 ARM64* on *Surface Pro X 1876 128GB*.
I flashed USB using latest Rufus version with *Windows 10 ARM64 1903 Enterprise* ISO.

I have an adapter (USB -> USB-C), secure boot is disabled from UEFI and disks are empty.

What did I tried (in Rufus):

- `GPT, UEFI (without CSM), FAT32, 4096b` - Windows is booting, I can see window where, I can choose language, date and keyobard, but I can't do anything from keyboard, touchpad or external mouse. Screen just freezed.
- `GPT, UEFI (without CSM), NTFS, 4096b` - Device is starting and freezing on Windows Surface logo.
- `MBR, BIOS (or UEFI-CSM), NTFS, 4096b` - I guess device can't see bootable USB and is booting in UEFI - I'm able to use touchpad, keyboard and external mouse.

(different USB also with adapter)

- `GPT, UEFI (without CSM), FAT32, 16kb` - Windows is booting, I can see window where, I can choose language, date and keyobard, but I can't do anything from keyboard, touchpad or external mouse. Screen just freezed.

Comment: Does ARM even understand MBR/GPT?  It has to be FAT32 but the operating system installation process for ARM devices is entirely different.

Comment: You shove using the recovery image: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/surface/forum/all/surface-pro-x-which-win-10-version-reinstall/26270a61-0818-4f1c-8ca6-b6a7d1350e0b#:~:text=Use%20a%20USB%20recovery%20drive%20to%20reset%20your,10%20If%20prompted%2C%20select%20Repartition%20the%20drives.%20

Comment: The ARM ISO your attempting to use is designed for device manufacturers who would customize the image for their device

Comment: I tried with last point of the [article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4023511/surface-boot-surface-from-a-usb-device). Formatted with FAT32 and ISO image with Windows 10 ARM64 Enterprise. Windows is booting, but I can't do anything in language selection step. When it comes about recovery image - there is only Windows 10 Home, but I need Enterprise, how to accomplish it?

Comment: The image you are attempting to use is meant for experienced users creating their own device image.

Comment: where did you get the ""Windows 10 ARM64 1903 Enterprise ISO"" ??

Comment: From partner.microsoft.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I was stupid because I thought that it not possible to change licence from Home to Enterprise.

I installed `Windows 10 Home` from generated ISO using [Surface Recovery Image](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/surfacerecoveryimage) (thank you @Ramhound!) with formatted USB (FAT32) drive.

After I installed the system I was able to activate `Windows 10 Enterprise` with the key:

```
NPPR9-FWDCX-D2C8J-H872K-2YT43
```

The system downloaded some files and rebooted.

After this I added the workstation to my domain and I was able to change the license with my own (digital, based on domain) and everything works great.